# Get the suffix from a list of similar string

Tags: python, prefix, suffix

```
# code to get commonprefix
    def commonprefix(m):
        if not m: return ''
        s1 = min(m)
        s2 = max(m)
        for i, c in enumerate(s1):
            if c != s2[i]:
                return s1[:i]
        return s1
#code to get the different suffix 
    strList = map(str, objList)
    strList = map(lambda x: x.replace('', ''), strList)  

# My code to get the different suffix of each element of a list 

    for i in range(len(liste)):

        Listelement = liste[i]["title"].tolist()
        common_name = commonprefix(Listelement)
        try:
            strList = map(str, Listelement) 
            strList = map(lambda x: x.replace(common_name, ''), strList)
            print(Listelement)
        except:
            pass

# this is how my "Listelement" variable look like

    ['Le Coton Coton Extra Doux Boîte 100pce - CHANEL']
    ['Allure Eau De Toilette Vaporisateur 50ml - CHANEL', 'Allure Eau De Toilette Vaporisateur 100ml - CHANEL']
    ['Allure Eau De Toilette Vaporisateur 50ml - CHANEL', 'Allure Eau De Toilette Vaporisateur 100ml - CHANEL']
    ['Eau De Cologne Les Exclusifs De Chanel 75ml - CHANEL', 'Eau De Cologne Les Exclusifs De Chanel 200ml - CHANEL']
    ['Eau De Cologne Les Exclusifs De Chanel 75ml - CHANEL', 'Eau De Cologne Les Exclusifs De Chanel 200ml - CHANEL']
```

Hi guys I have a small problem to find the suffix of my list of products. I got the common prefix function which give me for my list the correct answer but when i try to remove the common_prefix for each element of each list, it doesn't work, do you have any idea why?
thank you so much

Comment: Can you make a Minimal Reproductible Example ? Here we don't know how to use your data, neither what `liste` is

Comment: May you please exemplify your definition of "common prefix" and "common suffix" explicitly? Especially for the suffix, should it be `ml - CHANEL` or `CHANEL`?

Comment: for example for the second list , the suffix would be ['50ml - CHANEL', '100ml - CHANEL'] I just want to remove the similar part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need not reinvent the wheel for `os.path.commonprefix`.
2. In addition, you can use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) syntax on string instead of counting characters one-by-one.

Solution

```
import re
import os

ls = ['Allure Eau De Toilette Vaporisateur 50ml - CHANEL', 'Allure Eau De Toilette Vaporisateur 100ml - CHANEL']

# find common prefix
pfx = os.path.commonprefix(ls)
ans = [el[len(pfx):] for el in ls]
print(ans)  # ['50ml - CHANEL', '100ml - CHANEL']
```